# D3 Choropleth - determining if latitude/longitude points are currently in map view

Tags: d3.js, choropleth, map-projections

So I have a choropleth with a number of latitude/longitude based markers. Based on the current map view/zoom, I want to be able to tell what markers are in the current view. I kinda have this working, however, it's not accurate when the points are somewhat near the edge of the map and I have no idea why.

JSFiddle with a working example: https://jsfiddle.net/e39fgnjL/7/

[image: example one]

So you can see there are 4 points in view, but after filtering with my data points with the lat/long bounds, I only see 1.[image: Output]

Again once my points get near the edge, its stops working.

This is what I am using to generate the lat/long bounds of the map view.

```
function getScreenBounds() {
  return [getPoint(0,0), getPoint()];
}

function getPoint(x,y) {
  if (x == null) x = width;
  if (y == null) y = height;
  var container = svg.node();
  var pointContainer = container.ownerSVGElement || container;
  var point = pointContainer.createSVGPoint();
  point.x = x, point.y = y;
  point = point.matrixTransform(container.getScreenCTM().inverse());
  return projection.invert([point.x, point.y]);
}
```

Anyone help point me in the right direction as to why this isn't working?

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure this isn't doing what you expect because of the projection of latitude and longitude onto your rectangle.

Your rectangle edges don't line up with North-South East-West lines because of the projection issue (check out the Northern border... in lat/long terms, this is a straight East West line at a fixed latitude, but in your map it definitely curls up at the edge)

This means that counting the points in a lat/long box isn't the same as counting the points in your projected-to rectangle.

A simple fix would be to check each point to see if the *projection* of that point is in the bounds of your rectangle.